# Error: Connection is not in the READY state at ChannelEventHub._checkConnection

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am working on Hyperledger fabric project and while running command `node generateFights.js` i am receiving the below error.

```
Error: Connection is not in the READY state  at ChannelEventHub._checkConnection
```

I downloaded the source from [HyperLedger Fabric API](https://github.com/acloudfan/HLF-Fabric-API) to my local directory.

[image]

I open the directory in VisualStudio and run the command, but it throws me an error.

Just to be sure: - 
1. Docker Process is working. (Docker ps)
2. I have composer version installed ( v.0.19.0)
3. Node version - 8.11.1

What I tried to solve the issue: -

1. I begin the ./startFabric.sh
2. I installed the new network and started the process.
3. Imported the newly generated card.

Please suggest me what i need to do or learn to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error "Connection is not in a READY state" has been seen a few times as a result of an underlying grpc problem.  grpc v1.11.0 causes Composer to fail with this error, but v10.0.1 seems to be OK.  More details are described and workarounds are described in [this github issue](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3944).

It is likely that your app requires or has a dependency on a Composer client version with the grpc problem.  If you remove your Node modules folder and examine your package.json file you should be able to fix the version problem

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been addressed in the 1.1.2 release of the hyperledger fabric node sdk so you should ensure that your package.json dependencies will download this version and also ensure you clean up your node_modules directory and re-install your dependencies using `npm install`.

For Hyperledger composer users, v0.19.4 and beyond addresses this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to directory in which `composer-rest-server` and `composer-cli` npm modules are installed, then install the `grpc` npm module with version `1.10.1`.

Run the below command from both directories:

```
npm install --save grpc@1.10.1
```

It will solve your problem.

> **NOTE:** In my case, node modules were installed at
>   **/home/user_name/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/**. That is my **global** directory for **npm**.